# C# Application Settings store List of Tuples

Tags: c#, xml, tuples

in my c# program I want to store a list of Tuples in the program settings.
So I defined the type in the xml file:

```
<Setting Name="ScoreboarList"
 Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;System.Tuple&lt;System.String,System.Int32&gt;&gt;"
 Scope="User">
```

In the error list there is no error shown.
The Problem is that in the "settings-tab" there is an error: "Illegal character in path". (also shown on the following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahQm1.png))

So what can I do to eliminate this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't `"System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;System.Tuple&lt;System.String,System.Int32&gt;&gt;"` work?

Comment: Please read the question again, I renewed it

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the comma in the path name is not allowed. Therefore the solution consists of creating your own type. In tests I made, the `Tuple<,>` type did not work for settings. Fortunately it works with `ValueTuples`:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ScoreboarList : List<(string, int)>
    {
    }
}
```

However, you will not be able to assign values in the settings editor and will have to add them programmatically. This works for User scope settings but not for Application scope settings:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ScoreboarListSetting = new MyNamespace.ScoreboarList {
    ("Aaa", 11),
    ("Bbb", 22)
};
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

You can then access the settings with

```
foreach (var x in Properties.Settings.Default.ScoreboarListSetting) {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```